# Error Sending twilio SMS via parse

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, twilio

I'm trying to send a text message via Twilio and parse, but the cloud function produces "uh oh something went wrong." why?
Here's the xcode code:

```
//Sends SMS via Parse Cloud code to a number....//TODO test, debug...
+(void)sendSMSWithVerificationCode:(NSString *)verificationString toNumberString:(NSString *)phoneNumber {
NSMutableString * message=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Brighten verification code: "];
[message appendString:verificationString];
// Call our Cloud Function that sends an SMS with Twilio
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendSMSVerification"
                   withParameters:@{ @"number" : phoneNumber , @"messageString" : message} 
                             block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Verification code sent!"
                                                            message:nil
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
                            }];
```

}

and the cloud function looks as follows:

```
twilio.initialize("meh",",mehh"); //these are for testing; todo insert real ones when deploying

// Create the Cloud Function
Parse.Cloud.define("sendSMSVerification", function(request, response) {
```

// Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS

```
twilio.sendSMS({
     From: "111111111111111(my number as a string)",
To: request.params.number,
    Body: request.params.message //SMS Verification: 1234 or         whatever the specific number is...
  }, {
   success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
```

});
});

Comment: i am not sure but try From: number of country that you registers for.

Comment: sorry can you explain that further?

Comment: You should be logging the actual error, to find out why.  console.log(httpResponse) to start with.